# How to check if array index is not equal to argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, equality

Still learning Javascript by creating mini text RPG games via HTML pages :)
Good practice, trying to learn some new way or add some new better codes into my project.

Right now I'm trying to add language to my project via function;

```
language.addLang = function(name,id){
    if (id != this.log[id]) {
        this[name] = new Object;
        this.log[id] = name
        
    }
    
}
```

Edit;
Was trying to say if you can compare array index number to argument id number.
The name on the argument is just a language name, like English with a string value.
And id is just what array index it will be placed into. And also a conditional branch that will translate all text into that language for later use.

for people that wonder what log is;

```
language.log = [
  undefined, 'English','Swedish','Japanese','German'
]
```

Summary;
As above, log array length is right now 5.
So let's say I want to add a new language to my project that I will translate, later on, I can then write language.addLang('Chinese',5).
That will add 'Chinese' string into array index number 5.
However! If I would add from a different index number that already exists it will show some error instead of overwriting 'Chinese' to another language.

I hope this explains better than my last post.
I can translate it manually instead of adding a new object for each language.
But would be life-saving if I can compare argument number to index number.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question depends on what id and log are and we have no idea without a [mre]. As for array comparisons you should do a search on the topic. Two different array objects can have identical elements but they are not `==`

Comment: Please mention what `id` and `log[Id]` are. There is a comparison of `id != this.log[id]`.

Comment: Did update my post. Sorry I mean if you can compare array index number to this argument number. Example If I already have *language.log[1]* nothing will happen if I would write *language.addLang('English',1)* because 1 != this.log[1] is false.

Answer (score -1):

@Charliefl is right but I guess this may give you a clue to apply to your case by modifying according to your other code.

```js
var IncludedLanguages = [ 3 , 4 , 5 ] 
var LangObjectsArray = [] 


language.addLang = function(name,id){
   
   if ( IncludedLanuages.includes( id  ) != true )   {
      
            
        
      var obj = { "name" : name , "id" : id  }  
        LangObjectsArray.push( obj ) 
        IncludedLanguages.push( id )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, but when I did copy I got some error;
Uncaught ReferenceError: IncludedLanuages is not defined
Did also update my post.
All I wanted is to check if argument id is NOT the same number as an array index number.